# Making a sunburst diagram with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am learning D3 and love it! I am reading books, and I am stuck at an exercise making a sunburst diagram.

Here is my code so far:

```
<div id="sunburst"></div>

   <%--Then write/append script to container--%>
   <script type="text/javascript">

       <%--Calculate the maximum radius--%>
       var width = 640, height = 400, maxRadius = Math.min(width,height)/2;

       var svg = d3.select("sunburst").append("svg")
           .attr("width", width)
           .attr("height", height);

      //Center sunburst parameter at (0,0), so it's easier to parameters
      var g = sag.append("g");
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2) + "," + (height/2) + ")");

      //Scales are D3 objects used to convert input values into svg coordinates (i.e. pixels).
      var theta = d3.scale.linear()
          .range([0,2 * Math.PI]);
      var radius = d3.scale.sqrt()
          .range([0,maxRadius]);
```

At this point, the author says that the default domains of [0,1] are exactly what we need in this example. I am confused because theta and the radius can be more that 1, no? I must be missing something obvious.

Thank you very much for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

The values *output* from the `scale` function can indeed be more than 1. This is what the `range` defines. The `scale` function also has an *input* interval for the scaling, the `domain`, which is not specified in the example. The default for this is `[0, 1]`. The input values (across the `domain` interval) will then be mapped onto an output value (across the `range` interval), using the type of scaling specified: `linear` in this example.

So the full version would be:

```
  var theta = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0,1])
      .range([0,2 * Math.PI]);
```

meaning 0 maps to 0; 1 maps to 2 * pi; 0.5 maps to pi ...

Anyway, in the example from the exercise, I assume the inputs using the `theta` scale will be in the range `[0,1]`, hence the author's comment about this being an appropriate default.

Reference:
[d3 v3 API reference on github](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Quantitative-Scales.md)
[Example from dashingd3js.com](https://www.dashingd3js.com/d3js-scales)